# How to shutdown laptop automatically after certain process

Tags: windows-8, shutdown

I want to know how to shut down my laptop automatically after completion of certain task.
I know how to do that settings in control panel but i just want my laptop to shutdown automatically after completing the task.
Tasks for eg. download in progress, file copying, watching movie etc..

The setting in control panel never ask for the completion of the task. That just shuts down after certain interval of time.

Answer (score 0):

There are programs that allow you to monitor CPU and network usage and perform certain actions based on that. [AmpWinOff](http://www.ampsoft.net/utilities/WinOFF.php) and [SmartPower](http://getsmartpower.co.uk/) are two good options. While SmartPower offers a good [User guide](http://getsmartpower.co.uk/UserGuide.aspx), you may need to tinker a bit with AmpWinOff to get the hand of it.